# Is it possible to detect and drop duplicate data using ksql

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I have a simple question whether can we detect and drop duplicates in streaming data on kafka topic using KSQL.

Answer (score 0):

By default, tables are de-duped on keys. A new record for the same key will overwrite old events. If you need to "detect" and "process" the *old* data, as new events come in, then KSQL cannot do this.

If you need distinct values rather than by-key, you can create a table against some stream of events and filtering on `HAVING COUNT(field) = 1` [over a time window](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/concepts/time-and-windows-in-ksqldb-queries/#windows-in-sql-queries), which is the best you can do there. Ref - https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/finding-distinct-events/ksql.html

If you need indefinite time windows to ensure you only process a certain field once, then you'll want to use an external database, and optionally an internal cache, to perform lookups against. This would need to be done with a regular consumer, or Kafka Streams.